# Style combo box field in Ext JS

Tags: css, extjs, combobox, styles

I have a combo box that i am simply trying to make bold. The data is in a store. I can bold the item in the list, but i cannot bold the item after it is selected in the text box.

I have tried:

fontWeight: 'bold',
cls:  'make-bold',
itemCls:'make-bold',

I can bold the list via a template but not the item actually in the text field.

```
items:[
{
xtype: 'combobox',
name: 'inputType',
id: 'inputType',
padding : '6 5 5 5',
store: 'Codes',
displayField: 'display',
valueField: 'code',
value: 'Inp_CODE',
editable: false,
width: 80,
tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate', 
'<tpl for=".">','<div class="x-boundlist-item"><b>{display}</b></div>','</tpl>')
}, {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this did it

```
 fieldCls: 'make-bold', 
 style: {               
     fontWeight: 'bold' 
 }
```

why do i need both?

Comment: You don't need both. Maybe it's because of the `tpl` config. This [example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/form/forum-search.html) might prove helpful.

Comment: In the example you provided there is no bolding. I took the code and make a JSFiddle, and even there, i has to use both to make the text bold. So i know its not the tpl, or an edge case with my code.